# Нет кнопки удалить запись phpmyadmin

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, archlinux, manjaro

Установил phpmyadmin, добавил запись в таблицу, а удалить или редактировать запись кнопки нет, непонимаю в чем проблема, ос manjaro - linux

phpmyadmin ставил с официальных репов, кто - то сталкивался с этим, как решить ?

Скриншот прикреплен [image: Нет кнопки]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в отсутствии первичного ключа. Задайте его при помощи [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html). В качестве такого ключа можно использовать любое поле с уникальными значениями или создать новое. Например:

```
ALTER TABLE `join_info` ADD `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Comment: А можно подробнее ? я сделал как в ссылке, пока ничего не поменялось

Comment: @S1lllver Добавил пример в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нужен первичный ключ!

```
ALTER TABLE join_info
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Фактически данный ответ является [дубликатом ответа, принятого 6 лет назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670392/386633) без явных улучшений.